# Inserting Data with masterpage and using Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: sql, asp.net

I'm creating a simple form inserting data into SQL Server 2008 Express. I'm using a master page and make connection string by Ado.net entity data.

Data is not inserting. It just giving me Catch error ..

Please check my code is it any problem how to fix it

**Connection string**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbcheckingEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ABDULSAMAD-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=dbchecking;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="dbcheckingConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=ABDULSAMAD-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbchecking;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Code**

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection();

        try
        {
            Con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcheckingEntities"].ToString();
            Con.Open();
            string insertquery = "insert into userTable (firstname, lastname,email,password,gender,dob,regdatetime)values(@fname ,@lname,@email,@password,@gender,@dob,getdate())";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertquery, Con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFirstName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLastName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", RdoGender.SelectedValue);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txtPickDate.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Label1.Text = "User is added";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Error:";
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: it just giving me catch  result Label1.text = error; .. i mean data is not inserting into it  . it should say USER is ADDED

Comment: Read the exception and post here like this Label1.Text=ex.ToString()

Comment: Your insert statement is not formed correctly - Since you are using SQL function to get the current datetime `getdate()` in your query. You will need to create an additional paramter for `Date` and add to your `SQLCommand` - `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateNow", DateTime.Now);`